# Error generating source map - grunt and sass configuration

Tags: ruby, node.js, sass, gruntjs, npm

I am trying to use sass with grunt. I have installed ruby, sass and grunt in my path.
The versions are,

> node: 0.10.20
>     npm: 1.3.11
>     grunt-cli:  0.1.13
>     grunt: 0.4.5
>     sass: 3.4.4

my package json is,

```
"private": true,
"devDependencies": {
    "express": "4.x",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.4" 
}
```

my grunt file is,

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'style/style.css' : 'sass/home.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Now if i tried "grunt" command, i am getting the below error. Any help?

**run: grunt or grunt watch or grunt sass**

**error:**

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Error: Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for the source
 stylesheet.
         No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link
to.
        on line  of standard input
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Error: Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for t
he source stylesheet.
         No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link
to.
        on line  of standard input
  Use --trace for backtrace. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you don't have compass installed. You can run `gem install compass`. In your original example you had your grunt file set up to use compass which would have given you access to compass mixins and features.

Your code looks fine now and should work but seems to not be finding your files. I'll GI e it a go as well when I'm next to a computer.

In the meantime you can try the `sourcemap: none` option on the sass task.

Update:

Works perfectly fine for me. Could you run `tree -I node_modules` and post the output(unless you think there's any sensitive info) just to double check the files are in the right place?

I expect it to look something like this

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── package.json
├── sass
│   └── style.scss
└── style
    ├── style.css
    └── style.css.map
```

Second update:
Your packages seem significantly older than what's in my fresh setup. Either try starting from scratch or do the following:

Install npm-check-updates

```
npm install npm-check-updates
```

And then run the following

- `npm-check-updates` will tell you which packages are outdated
- `npm-check-updates -u` will update those packages in your `package.json`
- `npm update` to update all your outdated packages.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. Also i have edited my question with my current situation. but as i am beginner to this sass, is compass needed for grunt sass? anyway i just installed compass and tried also now. any updates?

Comment: Seems to not be able to find your stylesheet files. Have you made them yet and are they in the right place?

Comment: Updated the answer with a suggestion. I'll try running your example when im at a computer

Comment: Hi. i tried with 'tree -I node_modules'. but it shows some error saying that 'too many parameters'. may be i m wrong in command. Anyway the tree structure is correct. But one more thing, i have not created 'style.css.map'. What was that? will it automatically generate or i have to create. only difference with your structure - i dont have style.css.map. is that wrong?

Comment: No, that gets created by the sass task, it allows you to inspect the uncompiled source code from the browser. It's a really good feature, and it's what gets deactivated when you pass in 'sourcemap: none'. Have you tried that as well btw?

Comment: when i try 'sourcemap: none'. i am getting the warning "DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing --sourcemap without a value is deprecated.
Sourcemaps are now generated by default, so this flag has no effect." along with the same error.

Comment: Ok so  it should be inside the dist as `options: {sourcemap: 'none'}` just like your files JSON. The last question I have is what's in your SASS are there any imports, what does it look like?

Comment: just i tried a small example. So the code is $font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}

Comment: That all seems fine. The only other thing that differs from my setup is the versions of the packages. Try the second update from the answers and see where that gets you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. The error got fixed. Solution made: as you said i have updated all the node packages. Now it is running without error :) . cheers thanks again.

Comment: No problem, that was quite an annoying issue :) Hope you have better luck going forward

Answer (score -2):

updating node modules helped..

npm-check-updates will tell you which packages are outdated
npm-check-updates -u will update those packages in your package.json
npm update to update all your outdated packages.

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answer (which already recommends updating packages)?