# Error using Grunt watch and SASS

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

I am trying to use `grunt watch` t with SASS on Windows, but everytime I get an error

```
Waiting...
OK
>> File "scss\main.scss" changed.

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Error: Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for the source stylesheet.
No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link to.

on line  of standard input
Use --trace for backtrace.

Warning: Error: Error generating source map: couldn't determine public URL for the source stylesheet.
No filename is available so there's nothing for the source map to link to.

on line  of standard input
Use --trace for backtrace. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Completed in 0.769s at Wed May 13 2015 10:55:24 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
```

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501454/error-generating-source-map-grunt-and-sass-configuration) here, but that didn't work for me

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test thingy",
  "author": "Me",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.4"
  }
}
```

My Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/style.css' : 'sass/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

The software versions:

> grunt-cli v0.1.13
>
> grunt v0.4.5
>
> Sass 3.4.13 (Selective Steve)
>
> ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]
>
> Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
>
> npm 2.7.4
>
> node v0.12.2

I've tried updating all packages and even re-installed all the components but that didn't help. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable sourcemap and see if it works.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: 'none'
                },
                files: {
                    'css/style.css' : 'sass/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Your version of grunt-contrib-sass is obsolete try to change package.json to:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test thingy",
  "author": "Me",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey SharpEdge. Tnx for your reaction, I tried that but this was the result - 

    Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
    DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing --sourcemap without a value is deprecated.
    Sourcemaps are now generated by default, so this flag has no effect.

Comment: Don't know why I used 0.3.0 :S. Much appreciated :)